# selenium in python - one timeout causes all subsequent requests to timeout

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome driver version: 2.41
Chrome version: 69.0.3497.92

Here's my code sending multiple requests to one webdriver with exception handling:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

for link in links:
    try:
        driver.get(link)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        # do something
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        # do some other thing
        continue
```

The expected behavior was if a TimeoutException is thrown, I would just continue making requests to the next link and so on. However, what I am getting is that when one TimeoutException occurs, all the rest of the links also throw TimeoutExceptions.

Here's the the relevant log from chrome's logger.

> ```
> [1536872569.507][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 29.449
> [1536872569.509][INFO]: Timed out. Stopping navigation...
> [1536872569.509][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Page.stopLoading (id=1243) {
>
> }
> [1536872569.509][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Page.stopLoading (id=1243) {
>
> }
> [1536872569.509][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=1244) {
>    "expression": "1"
> }
> [1536872569.510][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.002
> [1536872569.513][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: timeout
> [1536872569.513][INFO]: RESPONSE Navigate timeout
>   (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.92)
> [1536872569.516][INFO]: COMMAND Navigate {
>   "sessionId": "9caf0bad68147065f14c9c22632cd6d8",
>    "url": "www.example.com"
> }
> [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Page.frameStoppedLoading {
>    "frameId": "620369B66F0605C0CE359F34F9D95E36"
> }
> [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Runtime.evaluate (id=1244) {
>    "result": {
>       "description": "1",
>       "type": "number",
>       "value": 1
>    }
> }
> [1536872569.516][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
> [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=1245) {
>    "expression": "1"
> }
> [1536872569.517][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Runtime.evaluate (id=1245) {
>    "result": {
>       "description": "1",
>       "type": "number",
>       "value": 1
>    }
> }
> [1536872599.516][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000
> [1536872599.518][INFO]: Timed out. Stopping navigation...
> [1536872599.518][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Page.stopLoading (id=1246) {
>
> }
> [1536872599.518][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Page.stopLoading (id=1246) {
>
> }
> [1536872599.518][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=1247) {
>    "expression": "1"
> }
> [1536872599.518][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.002
> [1536872599.522][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: timeout
> [1536872599.522][INFO]: RESPONSE Navigate timeout
>   (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.92)
> [1536872599.524][INFO]: COMMAND Navigate {
>    "sessionId": "9caf0bad68147065f14c9c22632cd6d8",
>    "url": "www.example2.com"
> }
> ```

The following are differences I found when comparing this event to other subsequent requests that finished without any exceptions.

1) `DEVTOOLS EVENT Page.frameStoppedLoading` comes immediately after sending a request to the new 'www.example.com' link.

2) the response to `DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=1244)`, which was sent from the previous link, is logged after the request to the new URL.

**Question:** is there any other way to handle this other than restarting the driver with each TimeoutException?

If someone could also elaborate on the behavior I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE:

From reading the logs further I realized that immediately trying to send another request results in the request not being sent at all. And the 2 observations I made in my original post occur with successful requests so you can ignore that.

Here's a comparison of the logs of successful consecutive requests vs consecutive requests following a Timeout Exception handling.

When the chrome driver starts, the browser session gets an id (later referred to as frameId).

> ```
>    [1536915601.693][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:34899/json
>    [1536915601.694][DEBUG]: DevTools response: [ {
>       "description": "",
>       "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:34899/devtools/page/A417CC5AE2C87A4D0FC64CF66B54ED72",
>       "id": "A417CC5AE2C87A4D0FC64CF66B54ED72",
>       "title": "data:,",
>       "type": "page",
>       "url": "data:,",
>       "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:34899/devtools/page/A417CC5AE2C87A4D0FC64CF66B54ED72"
>    } ]
> ```

Now **case 1:** normal request following a successful response:

> ```
>   [1536915607.033][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
>   [1536915607.033][INFO]: RESPONSE GetSource "\u003C!DOCTYPE html>\u003Chtml xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"ko\">\u003Chead>\u003Cmeta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/h       tml; charset=utf-8\" />\n\u003Cmeta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, in..."
>   [1536915607.044][INFO]: COMMAND Navigate {
>      "sessionId": "d11fb86ec1b49a141f99fe1ec4286a85",
>      "url": "http://www.gelloy.com/product/detail.html?product_no=438&cate_no=30&display_group=1"
>   } 
>  # ------ skip for concisiveness ----- #
>  [1536915607.044][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
>   [1536915607.044][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Page.navigate (id=49) {
>      "url": "http://www.gelloy.com/product/detail.html?product_no=438&cate_no=30&display_group=1"
>   }
>   [1536915609.244][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Page.navigate (id=49) {
>      "frameId": "A417CC5AE2C87A4D0FC64CF66B54ED72",
>      "loaderId": "0EB53CDA615428AA73A9DB67F5FF65E1"
>   }
> ```

Here, I can see that
 - `COMMAND Navigate` - prepares the next request
 - `COMMAND Page.navigate` - sends out the request
 - `RESPONSE Page.navigate` - returns with frameId given at the beginning

**vs**

**case 2:** request sent right after timeout is triggered:

> ```
>   [1536872569.513][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: timeout
>   [1536872569.513][INFO]: RESPONSE Navigate timeout
>   (Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.92)
>   [1536872569.516][INFO]: COMMAND Navigate {
>   "sessionId": "9caf0bad68147065f14c9c22632cd6d8",
>    "url": "www.example.com"
>   }
>   [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Page.frameStoppedLoading {
>    "frameId": "620369B66F0605C0CE359F34F9D95E36"
>   }
>   [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Runtime.evaluate (id=1244) {
>    "result": {
>       "description": "1",
>       "type": "number",
>       "value": 1
>    }
>   }
>   [1536872569.516][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
>   [1536872569.516][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=1245) {
>    "expression": "1"
>   }
>   [1536872569.517][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Runtime.evaluate (id=1245) {
>    "result": {
>       "description": "1",
>       "type": "number",
>       "value": 1
>    }
>   }
> [1536872599.516][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000
> ```

Following a timeout, however, I see the `COMMAND Navigate` with the next url to get, but `COMMAND Page.navigate` never happens. So when the 30 seconds are up from when `COMMAND Navigate` was created, the driver determines whether the page was loaded or not from the result of the lastest `RESPONSE Page.navigate`, which results in timeouts thereafter.

---

## Solution

I decided to close the driver with `driver.quit()` and reopen a new browser every time a Timeout Exception occurs. Putting a `time.sleep(1)` before continuing with the loop also seems to work, but I can't be certain that 1 second is enough.

Here's what my updated code looks like:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

for link in links:
    try:
        driver.get(link)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        # do something
        driver.quit()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)           
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        # do some other thing
        continue
```